# How can I check if a string item within an array is all uppercase?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called Symbols, it gets strings found by a regular expression pushed into it.
I now need to sort through the array and find out if there is a string that has every letter capitalized in it. I have tried similar things in the classified function below everything has returned "false" thus far, even if there is an element that is just "AAAA"

```
let symbols = [];
let regr = RegExp(/{\$([^\$]+)\$}/, 'g')

function genToken(inStream){
    let array;
    let vrtStream = inStream.trim();
    console.log("Extracting meaningful symbols from string: ", vrtStream);

    while((array = regr.exec(vrtStream)) !== null){
        console.log(`Meaningful symbol: ${array[0]} found and assigned. Next starts at ${regr.lastIndex}.`)
        symbols.push(array)
    }
    if(symbols.length > 0){ 
        for(index = 0; index < symbols.length; index++){
            symbols[index].splice(0, 1);
            console.log(`${symbols[index].length} meaningful symbols currently indexed.`);
            console.log(symbols);
            }// end for
        return classify(symbols); 
        } else {
            console.log("no elements in array");
        }

    function classify(data, index){
        console.log("Classify called", symbols)
        //symbols is data

        symbols.forEach(function(item, index, array){
            if(item.toUpperCase == true){
                console.log(`${item} is upper`)
            } else {
                console.log('false');
            }
        })
        
    }    
}
```

Comment: I should mention that the second function, classify, is nested within the first, and the symbols array is returned to the second function so it maintains all the data it had before.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in what you've posted. Please update the question with the actual code, input and expected output.

Comment: I've found a syntax error. There is no `{ }` for `getStuff()` function.

Comment: Added full code

Comment: `item.toUpperCase()` converts all letters in `item` to uppercase, it does not check if `item` is all uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know which items in an array are all caps, you can map over them and use the regexp `test` method:

```js
const arr = ['aaa', 'aAa', 'AAa', 'AAA', 'AAAa'];
const allCaps = arr.map(el => /^[A-Z]+$/.test(el));
console.log(allCaps);
```

If you just need to find the first one, or filter to only include the ones that match, you can use the `find` or `filter` array methods:

```js
const arr = ['aaa', 'aAa', 'AAa', 'AAA', 'AAAa', 'BBBB'];
const first = arr.find(el => /^[A-Z]+$/.test(el));
console.log(first);

const all = arr.filter(el => /^[A-Z]+$/.test(el));
console.log(all);
```

Comment: I have been messing around with the find function on and off with this problem, thank you for showing me how to do this with regex I appreciate it Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to check if string is all uppercase is create uppercase string from it and then check if it is same as old string

```js
// just some dummy data
const array = ["some data", "AAAA", "AAaA", "AAAAAB", "ALL_CAPS"];

// actual code to check if string is all uppercase
const allCapsArray = array.filter((str) => str.toUpperCase() === str);

// just printing output
console.log(allCapsArray);
```